# Maximum slope of a function related to a signal

Tags: calculus

A signal x(t) inceases linearly to the value 2 at $t=2$, starting from $t=1$.  It stays constant for $t \in [2,3]$ then decreases linearly to 0 at $t=5$.  Let $y(t)=x(2t-1)$.

What is the maximum and minimum value of the slope of y(t) for $t \in [0, \infty]$?

I know $x(t)$ is a piecewise function.  But now the trouble comes from computing the derivative of $y(t)$

$y(t)=x(t)(2t-1)$

When I try to compute the derivative, I get $\dot{y} = \dot{x}(2t-1)+2x$

However, I'm not sure what to do after here to compute the maximum/minimum slope because to me it looks like the answer is +infinity, -infinity for both.  I assume the derivative I computed is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derivatives are really nice, but sometimes it's helpful to get an intuitive understanding of what's going on. Especially when it comes to signals and signal processing, having a basic idea of how a signal can be transformed is helpful.

So instead of slapping a dot on variables and do the math accordingly, I try to solve this a little bit differently.

$y(t)$ is just a transformed version of $x(t)$. Let's take a look at what happens to the plot of a function $f(t)$ when various tranformations are applied to it. Red denotes modifications of the value of the function whereas blue denotes modifications of the parameter. If the parameter $a$ has the neutral value, nothing happens.

$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
\text{Transformation} & \text{Result} & \text{neutral value}\\
\hline
f(t) + \color{red}{a} &  \text{The plot moves up } a\gt0 \text{ or down } a\lt0 & 0\\
f(t + \color{blue}{a}) &  \text{The plot moves to the left } a\gt0 \text{ or to the right } a\lt0 & 0\\
\hline
\color{red}{a}f(t)  &  \text{The plot is strechted along the vertical axis } a\gt1 \text{ or squished } a\lt1 & 1\\
f(\color{blue}{a}t) &  \text{The plot is squished along the horizontal axis } a\gt1 \text{ or strechted } a\lt1 & 1\\
\end{array}
$$

In your case
$$y(t)=x(2t-1)$$

$x(t)$ is squished along the $t$ axis by a factor of 2 and then moved to the right by 1. Let's take a look at the discrete values you provided in your question. I include $t=-1$ and interpolate the value at $t=4$:

$$
\begin{array}{r|c}
t & x(t)\\
\hline
-1 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
1 & 0\\
2 & 2\\
3 & 2\\
4 & 1\\
5 & 0\\
\end{array}
$$

Let's now extend the table to see the values for $2t-1$ and $y(t)$:

$$
\begin{array}{r|c|r|c}
t & x(t) & 2t-1 & y(t) = x(2t-1)\\
\hline
-1 & 0 &\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
2 & 2 & 3 & 2\\
3 & 2 & 5 & 0\\
4 & 1 &\\
5 & 0 & \\
\end{array}
$$

I implied that $x(-1) = 0$ and did only add those values for $2t-1$ and $y(t)$ that are within the known interval of $x(t)$.

Here's how both plots look like with red lines that connect the corresponding points:

[image: both plots]

You can visually see how $y(t)$ is a squished version of $x(t)$. With that understanding of how $x(t)$ is transformed, you can reason about the slope of $y(t)$:

The biggest slope of $x(t)$ is 2 for $t\in [1,2]$ and smallest one is -1 for $t\in [3,5]$. Squishing the function along the $t$ axis means squishing those intervals. **If the height difference of a slope stays the same, but it's time difference is halved, the slope doubles.**

That means the biggest slope of $y(t)$ is 4 for $t\in [0, 1.5]$ and smallest one is -2 for $t\in [2,3]$.